# tm package: inspect() returning char count, rather than content

Tags: r, tm

Whenever I run the `inspect()` function in the [tm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) R package, I'm getting a char count back instead of the content of the documents. This is happening regardless what data source I'm using.

Here is my code:

```
library(tm)

data <- c("one two three", "two three four", "three four five")

corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(data))

inspect(corp)
```

My output example:

```
inspect(corp)

VCorpus

Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 3

[[1]]
PlainTextDocument

Metadata:  7

Content: chars: 13

[[2]]
PlainTextDocument

Metadata:  7

Content:  chars: 14

[[3]]
PlainTextDocument
Metadata:  7

Content:  chars: 15
```

but what I want is:

```
[[1]]
PlainTextDocument

Metadata:  7

one two three

[[2]]
PlainTextDocument

Metadata:  7

two three four

[[3]]
PlainTextDocument
Metadata:  7

three four five
```

Here is another example using the Ovid text files that come default with the TM Package and referenced in this "Introduction to tm Package" at the beginning by Ingo Feinerer. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf

Code:

```
txt <- system.file("texts", "txt", package = "tm")
ovid <- VCorpus(DirSource(txt, encoding = "UTF-8"),
 + readerControl = list(language = "lat"))
inspect(ovid[1:2])
```

What I want and what it should output:

```
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 2

 [[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
  Si quis in hoc artem populo non novit amandi,
hoc legat et lecto carmine doctus amet.
arte citae veloque rates remoque moventur,
arte leves currus: arte regendus amor.
curribus Automedon lentisque erat aptus habenis,
Tiphys in Haemonia puppe magister erat:
me Venus artificem tenero praefecit Amori;
Tiphys et Automedon dicar Amoris ego.
ille quidem ferus est et qui mihi saepe repugnet:
sed puer est, aetas mollis et apta regi.
Phillyrides puerum cithara perfecit Achillem,
atque animos placida contudit arte feros.
qui totiens socios, totiens exterruit hostes,
creditur annosum pertimuisse senem.
[[2]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
quas Hector sensurus erat, poscente magistro
verberibus iussas praebuit ille manus.
Aeacidae Chiron, ego sum praeceptor Amoris:
saevus uterque puer, natus uterque dea.
sed tamen et tauri cervix oneratur aratro,
frenaque magnanimi dente teruntur equi;
et mihi cedet Amor, quamvis mea vulneret arcu
pectora, iactatas excutiatque faces.
quo me fixit Amor, quo me violentius ussit,
```

What it outputs for me:

```
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 2

[[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 49
Content:  chars: 48
Content:  chars: 46
Content:  chars: 47
Content:  chars: 0
Content:  chars: 52
Content:  chars: 48
Content:  chars: 46
Content:  chars: 46
Content:  chars: 53
Content:  chars: 0
Content:  chars: 49
Content:  chars: 49
Content:  chars: 50
Content:  chars: 49
Content:  chars: 44

[[2]]
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 48
Content:  chars: 47
Content:  chars: 47
Content:  chars: 48
Content:  chars: 46
Content:  chars: 0
Content:  chars: 48
Content:  chars: 49
Content:  chars: 45
Content:  chars: 47
Content:  chars: 45
Content:  chars: 0
Content:  chars: 51
Content:  chars: 42
Content:  chars: 45
Content:  chars: 48
Content:  chars: 44
```

Comment: Can you provide at least some of your text content and the code you ran to reach inspect(corp)?

Comment: I added it into the original question

Comment: I ran your code on data and got exactly what you want.  Perhaps you need to update your tm package?  > inspect(corp)
<<VCorpus (documents: 3, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>

[[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
one two three

[[2]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
two three four

[[3]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
three four five

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in `tm 0.6.2`

Answer (score 3):

Version 0.6-1 of the `tm` package changed the way that documents are printed to screen. It now outputs a compact representation of the document rather than the document text itself.

To obtain the document text, you'll need to apply the `as.character()` function to the documents in the corpus.

For example, using the ovid example (shown here using `tm` version 0.6-2):

```
> txt <- system.file("texts", "txt", package = "tm")
> ovid <- VCorpus(DirSource(txt, encoding = "UTF-8"),
    readerControl = list(language = "lat"))
```

The new inspect function outputs a compact representation of each document:

```
> inspect(ovid[1:2])
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 2

[[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 676

[[2]]
<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 700
```

To obtain the full text of each document, apply the `as.character()` function to the document you want to examine (note that the output has been truncated):

```
> as.character(ovid[[1]])
 [1] "    Si quis in hoc artem populo non novit amandi,"    
 [2] "         hoc legat et lecto carmine doctus amet."     
 [3] "    arte citae veloque rates remoque moventur,"       
 [4] "         arte leves currus: arte regendus amor."
```

To clean up the output for display, combine the above with the `writeLines()` function:

```
> writeLines(as.character(ovid[[1]]))
    Si quis in hoc artem populo non novit amandi,
         hoc legat et lecto carmine doctus amet.
    arte citae veloque rates remoque moventur,
         arte leves currus: arte regendus amor.
```

To do this for multiple documents in a corpus, combine the above with the `lapply()` function (output truncated):

```
> lapply(ovid[1:2], as.character)
$ovid_1.txt
 [1] "    Si quis in hoc artem populo non novit amandi,"    
 [2] "         hoc legat et lecto carmine doctus amet."     
 [3] "    arte citae veloque rates remoque moventur,"       
 [4] "         arte leves currus: arte regendus amor." 

$ovid_2.txt
 [1] "    quas Hector sensurus erat, poscente magistro"   
 [2] "         verberibus iussas praebuit ille manus."    
 [3] "    Aeacidae Chiron, ego sum praeceptor Amoris:"    
 [4] "         saevus uterque puer, natus uterque dea."
```

Finally, to clean up this output and somewhat replicate the previous inspect behavior, try using the `l_ply()` function in the `plyr` package as follows (output truncated):

```
> l_ply(ovid[1:2], function(doc) { 
    print(doc) # output summary of document
    writeLines("") # output blank line between results
    writeLines(as.character(doc)) # output clean document text
    writeLines("") # output blank line between results
  })

<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 676

    Si quis in hoc artem populo non novit amandi,
         hoc legat et lecto carmine doctus amet.
    arte citae veloque rates remoque moventur,
         arte leves currus: arte regendus amor.

<<PlainTextDocument>>
Metadata:  7
Content:  chars: 700

    quas Hector sensurus erat, poscente magistro
         verberibus iussas praebuit ille manus.
    Aeacidae Chiron, ego sum praeceptor Amoris:
         saevus uterque puer, natus uterque dea.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because anythings was modified in the latest version package 'tm' 0.6-1, on may, 07. I only retrieved the version 0.6 and it works.

1. Download the archive: tm_0.6.tar.gz in this link: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tm/
2. Install via RStudio: Tools > Install Packages > Package Archive File > select tm_0.6.tar.gz and Install.

only this :)